# how to let "auto" convert type

Tags: c++, proxy, auto

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bitset<8> c = 0;
    c[3]=1;
    auto s = c[5];
    s = !s;
    cout << c[5];
}
```

This program will treat s as a class, which makes the result c[5]=1. It seems that 
    auto& s = c[5];

### is required to do this (of course it makes complication error). Thus what to do?

Some showed that they don't understand me very well, so maybe I should redescribe the problem:
For a proxy if I use "auto" to get the value, I expect to get the type of property.get() but I get the type of property (the proxy itself). 
It's not a good idea that I use "!!c[5]" or "bool s" if it is in a large project and the type of s is more complex.

Comment: I don't get a compilation error, it works as expected for me. Could you go into more depth?

Comment: You'll have to explain a bit more ... what result do you expect and what do you actually see? In the code you have right now, the value of `c[5]` should be negated because of `s = !s`.

Comment: What is your question? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @058094041: `auto& s = c[5];` is an error (binding a non-const reference to a temporary). If your compiler accepts it, it is not in compliance with the standard.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I didn't think that was OP's question. If that was infact what OP was asking, I apologise. The wording is confusing.

Comment: The reason you get the proxy itself when using `auto` is that the subscript operator must return the proxy or this expression would not work: `c[3] = 1;`.  If `c[3]` returned an rvalue then the assignment becomes impossible (you can't have your cake and eat it too).  To get an rvalue you must extract it from the proxy with a cast (explicit or implicit). If the `bitset` is declared `const`, then the assignment is forbidden anyway so returning an rvalue makes sense.  I don't understand your last sentence - how can `s` be more complex than a `bool` (or the proxy) if you are using a `bitset`.

Comment: It needn't be a bitset. Returning the proxy is okay but it should turn into bool (or anything in other cases) when used, not when I force it to be a bool

Comment: I don't think you understood me.  If `auto s = c[5]` resulted in `s` being a `bool` then the line immediately above, `c[3] = 1`, would not work because you would be assigning 1 to a boolean rvalue (`c[3]` would return a `bool`) and *not* the `bitset`.  When you use the `auto` keyword you are telling the compiler not to use implicit type conversion. Effectively you are saying 'just give me whatever type the function returns', which in this case is the proxy type. The proxy won't 'turn into' a `bool` unless you explicitly cast it because the compiler has no idea what type you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Not pretty, but this seems to work:

```
auto s = !!c[5];
```

Also, you could always have an explicit `(int)` cast, but you must have a reason for not doing that...

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is for taking the actual type of the object. If you want a different type (i.e. not the proxy reference), just don't use `auto`:

```
bool s = c[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::bitset::operator[]
```

Returns rvalue, so you can't have reference to it. You can only have a reference to the whole bitset.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `std::bitset::operator[]` in this context returns a reference to a `std::bitset::reference`, which provides 'reference semantics' for bitset bits.  See my answer.  I suspect the OP *wants* an rvalue and is disappointed when modifications to the returned value modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question - although it could be worded better.

If I understand it correctly, you are expecting that `s` should be constructed as a `bool` and receive the value `false` but instead it is constructed as a `bitset::reference` with the value `0`, which you are then able to negate, which of course changes the original `bitset` and causes `cout << c[5]` to emit `1`.

This result is actually expected.  If you read the documentation for [std::bitset::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operator[]/) you will see that there are two overloads:

```
bool operator[] (size_t pos) const;
reference operator[] (size_t pos);
```

With the following commentary:

> If the bitset object is const-qualified, the function returns a bool value. Otherwise, it returns a value of the special member type reference, which emulates a bool value with *reference-semantics* with respect to one bit in the bitset (see [bitset::reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/reference/)).

So basically you want the first version but are getting the second.

To achieve what you are after you must do any of the following:

1. Declare an explicit type `bool` instead of using `auto` e.g. `bool s = c[5];`
2. Use an explicit cast to `bool`, or an integer type with implicit conversion to `bool` e.g. `auto s = static_cast<bool>(c[5]);`
3. Declare the `bitset` as `const` e.g. `const bitset<8> c = 16; auto s = c[5];`
4. Cast the bitset to `const` before accessing the bit e.g. `auto s = static_cast<const bitset<8>>(c)[5];`

@ly000 is wrong that you can't have a reference to a bit in a `bitset` because that is exactly what you are getting here (this is what *reference semantics* means) - although perhaps what he means is that you can't have a reference in the traditional sense but need the wrapper provided by the `bitset::reference` object returned by `operator[]`.

The solution by @Sam Varshavchik, works because it forces the `bitset::reference` object returned by `operator[]` to a `bool` in order to do the 'not' operation - but personally I don't like this as it obscures your intent somewhat.  In my opinion the best option is option one, or if you don't need to change the bitset, option three.

Incidentally, it is redundant to initialize the `bitset` to 0 as you do because the default constructor will initialize all bits to zero.